# how do I reference first argument of an enumeration?

Tags: python, enumerate

I am writing code with enumerate() in Python, and I am having issues with referencing the first argument in enumerate:

For example, let nums be temperatures of different days:

```
nums = [1,5,20,9,3,10,50,7]
array = []

for j, distance in enumerate(nums): 
    for k, distance2 in enumerate(nums[1:],1): 
        if nums[j] < nums[k]: 
            array.append(distance2[j]-distance[k])
```

So, the challenge I have is: how do I reference the 'distance' and 'distance2' of each element respectively in my enumerations?

The aim of the problem is to determine for each day, how many days you'll have to wait for a warmer day, so for the example above, the output would be [1,1,4,3,1,1,0,0]; where there are no warmer days ahead, return 0.

Thanks

Comment: `enumerate` will give you the index and the value from the list. `distance` is an `int` from `nums` and `distance2` is also an `int` from `nums` which means they are not subscriptable.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you include your expected output?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need enumerate at all here if all you need to end up doing is `if distance < distance2` and `array.append(distance2 - distance)`.

Comment: Okay, I have put up the full question. Sorry Kemp with the question I don't think that'll work but I know you suggested your solution before I edited my question above.

Comment: How do you define a 'warmer day'? Maybe you can add it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the distance based off the indexes not the values at the index.

You should not restart your subscript and inner index at `1` each time but rather at `i` each iteration.

```py
nums = [1, 5, 20, 9, 3, 10, 50, 7]
array = []

for i, curr_temp in enumerate(nums):
    days = 0
    for j, future_temp in enumerate(nums[i:], i):
        if curr_temp < future_temp:
            # Set Days to Distance between Indexes
            days = j - i
            # Stop Looking Once Higher Value Found
            break

    array.append(days)

print(array)
```

Output:

```py
[1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: One more question please- why does the days=0 sit in the scope it is in? Because I tried moving it to a previous scope and I got the wrong answer. Just curious how this works, thanks!

Comment: The outer loop goes through start points, the inner loop goes from the current day forward. With every new "start" day the number of days until the next hotter day needs to be reset to 0. Which is why it's the first step in the outer loop body.

Comment: Thanks Henry, that makes so much sense. Could I ask for another small favour if you have the time. Is it possible to share. a solution but using a stack? I've tried so many things but couldn't get it right. Not sure if I'll have to post a separate question, but will do if necessary!